# How to exit a git merge asking for commit message?

Tags: git, merge

I'm using git. I did a normal merge, but it keeps asking this:

```
# Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary,
# especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch.
```

And even if I write something, I can't exit from here. I can't find docs explaining this. How should I do?

Comment: press ESC :wq   it's a vim syntax ;)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is depend on the editor you're using.

If [vim](/questions/tagged/vim) you can use <kbd>ESC</kbd> and <kbd>:wq</kbd> or <kbd>ESC</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>zz</kbd>. Both command save file and exit.

You also can check `~/.gitconfig` for editor, in my case (`cat ~/.gitconfig`):

```
[user]
    name = somename
    email = somemail@gmail.com
[core]
    editor = vim
    excludesfile = /home/mypath/.gitignore_global
[color]
  ui = auto
  # other settings here
```

Comment: It does not and will not work

Answer (score 6):

The answer marked correct here did not work for me as after you quit the editor with `wq` or `:q!`, the file gets saved and the merge happens.

The alternative, I've found for now is to suspend the vim process by using a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> and then aborting the merge with a `git merge --abort` and then killing the background process (you'll see the PID when you do the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Deserves more likes.

Comment: Killing the process manually is overly complicated. It's more straightforward to either (1) erase the commit message and save the file (which should abort the merge becaue of empty commit message) or (2) save the commit message and do `git reset --hard @^1` which will undo the merge commit.

Comment: The `:cq` answers below is my preferred method now.

Answer (score 4):

I did not find the answer to the question here if you happen *not* to be using the `vim` editor. My editor for WSL appeared to be `nano` and the only way I could get out of the `MERGE_MSG` screen was to use: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Exiting nano in this way still continues with the git merge.  I am currently looking for a way to avoid that - exit nano and abort the merge.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your editor. In `vi` and `vi` forks like vim, exiting by either saving (`wq`) or force exiting without saving (`q!`) will **NOT** prevent merge to continue. In order to stop merge to continue, you need to exit vim with an error.

Exit vim using `cq!` will prevent merge to happen.

Answer (score 2):

Also late to this but to build on [@CodeTalker's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/676584/184680):

If you are using `vi` or `vim`, the `:help cquit` documentation in vim states

```
:cq[uit][!] {N}     Quit Vim with error code {N}.  {N} defaults to one.
            Useful when Vim is called from another program:
            e.g., a compiler will not compile the same file again,
            `git commit` will abort the committing process, `fc`
            (built-in for shells like bash and zsh) will not
            execute the command, etc.
            {N} can also be zero, in which case Vim exits
            normally.
            WARNING: All changes in files are lost!  Also when the
            [!] is not used.  It works like ":qall!" |:qall|,
            except that Vim returns a non-zero exit code.
```

note the call out for `git commit` in that snippet

Answer (score 0):

I know this may be late, however I have noticed that it only occurs if I make a commit to a branch is a bit more updated than the branch that i'm merging.

[image: Image to help with understanding]

It turns out that if I change a branch (i.e., add more files to the branch), and try and merge another branch into it, Git will request me to write a `MERGE_MSG` for that branch.

In this image, it shows that I added a LICENSE file in `master` and a `.gitignore` file in branch `npm-init`.

Because `master` contains a new file, LICENSE, and `npm-init` does not know about it, Git asked me to write a message about why I should merge it.

Similarly, I merged `add-eslint` into `add-dev` **before** I merged the changes in `install-deps`.

---

*I know this may be hard to understand (even for me at first), but I hope the image clears things up* :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the 'git commit' command on the git bash, you could use the 'git commit --m (Then the quoted description of the commit message).

My stance on this is as a result of my inability to exit the commit editor after getting there. Any contrary opinion is welcome anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Just open new git bash window in the same location and write the

```
$ git commit -m "<a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary>"
```

and this will finish the merge to your local branch.

After that you can push your local commit to the remote.

Comment: How would this terminate the editor that the user is stuck in?

Answer (score 0):

#### To Continue the Merge...

...save the message and exit the editor...somehow. See other answers for this!

#### Want to Abort the Merge?

Supply an empty message. This with get you to:

> Not committing merge; use 'git commit' to complete the merge.

- As suggested, you can manually continue with `git commit -m "...."`, `git commit --edit` or similar.
- `git merge --abort` will get you back to where you started.